# Rounding error when converting Double to Real in fortran

Tags: floating-point, type-conversion, fortran, rounding, rounding-error

i'm trying to convert a double into a real for some operations but i noticed an error.
i have a macro for reading purposes, `short` is 4 bytes, and `long` is 8 bytes.

this is the execution code :

```
print*, x, real(x, kind=short) 
print*, x*2.0, real(x*2.0, kind=short) 

print*, real( real(x, kind=short), kind=long) 
print*, real( real(x*2.0, kind=short), kind=long)
```

this prints out :

```
173.43304556187957 173.433044 
346.86609112375913 346.866089

173.43304443359375 
346.86608886718750
```

so first of all why do i even have any values after converting to real then back again? Shouldn't it be something like `173.43304400000000`?
And why are my values changing when i convert them? How can i change that ?

For info, fortran 2003, compiled with gfortran but i think we had the same problem with ifort.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. The values are stored as binary (base 2) floating point, and the extra fraction bits for double precision are binary zeroes, not decimal zeroes. Most decimal fractions don't convert exactly to binary (and vice-versa).

You can better see what is going on when you display the values in hexadecimal format. I used this program:

```
integer, parameter :: short = kind(0.0)
integer, parameter :: long = kind(0.0D0)
real(short) :: r4
real(long) :: r8

r8 = 173.43304556187957_long
print '(G0.16,1X,Z16.16)', r8,r8
r4 = r8
print '(G0.16,1X,Z8.8)',r4, r4
r8 = r4
print '(G0.16,1X,Z16.16)', r8,r8
end
```

and when I run it, I get:

```
173.4330455618796 4065ADDB825DBE6C
173.4330444335938 432D6EDC
173.4330444335938 4065ADDB80000000
```

Note that the reconversion to "long" just adds binary zeroes, not changing the value. By the way, using list-directed formatting can obscure details such as this.

Comment: Steve gave you the answer.  If you're interested in more detail, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: "Most decimal fractions don't convert exactly to binary (and vice-versa)." is amiss.  All binary fractions convert exactly to decimal -perhaps to a very long decimal fraction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would you recommend using the _Guard Digits_ section of the [link provided above](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) ? It seems simple enough and could work for my problems

Comment: I don't know if that's appropriate for your needs, based on the snippets you provided. That article is useful, though, and is a rehash of several earlier articles "The Perils of Floating Point" and others.